# Rename Computer on Reboot SCVMM

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'm using SCVMM to manage large lab environments comprised of a lot of machines, and while SCVMM itself has been a godsend in managing these I haven't been able to find an option to have windows prompt for a new computer name on first boot.

I found things like sysprep but I need to be able to rename a computer built from an SCVMM template, not a fresh install.  Would a one-time powershell script be the best route for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMM automaticly injects the computername (same as vm name) when you're creating a VM from a VM template (given that the template has prepared correctly). Sysprep is used in the background, but there's no need to interact with sysprep directly. This page has all the details, be sure to take note of the small print:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh427282.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

As far as I can remember, VMM will execute sysprep on the VM when you're creating a template based on "golden" VM, so you shouldn't have to do that beforehand. There's youtube videos describing the process as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the computername of the VM during installation we are using automation platform to provide some kind of Private Cloud solution we are using original SCVMM Script with a lot of Variables, you can get it when generating new VM at last step there's View Script on top right, so u can check all the settings

you can set that value with Computer name 
Set-SCVMConfiguration -VMConfiguration $virtualMachineConfiguration -Name "${name}" **-computername "${name}"** -VMHost $vmHost